# Move from Preferences Pane to Maps in android too quickly => Error. How do I fix?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm debugging an application I wrote, and I found a strange bug.

I've embedded a google map pane (with overlays) on Activity A. When I from A to the Preferences Activity, then immediately hit the back button to go back to Activity A, I get an arrayIndexOutOfBounds error.

The weird thing is that the stacktrace of the error doesn't mention my activity at all - the exception is all found in Google or Android classes.

If I wait as long as a second before hitting the "back" button, all is fine.

So, that's weird. What gives? How can I fix this, please?

This is a partial stacktrace of the error:

> 10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getIndexToDraw(ItemizedOverlay.java:211)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.draw(ItemizedOverlay.java:240)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at com.google.android.maps.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:179)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:42)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:530)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
>   10-31 00:54:09.434: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13126):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)

Comment: it would help to show some code - at least showing what happens when the activity comes back to the front i.e. `onResume()`